# Vue + Element UI: How to use a dynamic tooltip in a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am working on Element UI tables and I am trying to include a tooltip for one of my columns, however I can not figure out how to retrieve the prop to display it within the tooltip.

```html
<el-table-column
  label="Service Lines / MSDRG"
  prop="code"
  sortable
>
  <el-tooltip effect="dark" placement="top-start" content="some content here">
    {{code}}
  </el-tooltip>
</el-table-column>
```

Is there a way to get the `code` value to display within the `<el-tooltip>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [custom column template](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#custom-column-template) to access the slot scope of the cell:

```html
<el-table-column label="Service Lines / MSDRG" prop="code" sortable>

  <template slot-scope="slotData">
    <el-tooltip effect="dark" placement="top-start" content="some content here">
      <span>{{ slotData.row.code }}</span>
    </el-tooltip>
  </template>

</el-table-column>
```

The `<template>` tag pulls in the scoped slot data through the `slot-scope` attribute, and you can name the data whatever you like.  Here I've named it `slotData`, and so `slotData.row` refers to the data for the row.  Therefore, you can access the `code` field through `slotData.row.code`.

Be sure to wrap the value in some tag, like `<span>` in the example above.